# Why is this HTML formatting convention recommended?

Tags: html

I've been looking through a ton of sites recently to get a better understanding of how large websites structure their HTML5 pages.

I noticed that they tend to do

```
<script src="test.js"></script>
```

Instead of

```
<script src="test.js" />
```

But do

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css"/>
```

Instead of

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css"></link>
```

Even in this technique blog they do so, why is this a preferred design style?

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/25-html5-features-tips-and-techniques-you-must-know/

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/69913/why-dont-self-closing-script-tags-work

Comment: Short tag support for <script> isn't supported in some browsers. It's about compatibility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because the web is normalized and some things are possible according to the norm and some other aren't. With a logic behind being that some elements are naturally void and some others aren't.

From [the w3.org on the script element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/script.html) :

> A script element must have both a start tag and an end tag.

So you can't have

```
<script src="test.js" />
```

[On the link element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/link.html) :

> The link element is a void element. A link element must have a start
>   tag but must not have an end tag.

A `link` element, which can't have a content, can be written

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css"/>
```

or even (much better if you don't try to write XHTML)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
```

Comment: It's also the rule... not just the norm.

Comment: @BoltClock It might due to my poor mastering of the English language (or the fact I'm still drinking my first coffee) but I fail to see this distinction. What do you mean ?

Answer (score 1):

[According to the HTML standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html#h-18.2.1), the ending tag is required for the `script` tag, it can't be a self-closing tag.

Self-closing tags are used in XHTML for tags that doesn't require a closing tag in HTML, like the `link` and `input` tags.

Answer (score 1):

In HTML, there are tags which are always self-closed. For example,

`<hr>Some content here</hr>`

does not make any sense. In the same way, there are tags which cannot be self-closed.  tag is one of them.

I am not sure about the reason of no self-closed  tags, but the reason might come from the fact that the tag was intended to always contain code inside.